# What are the c# equivalents of of Java's getClass(), isAssignableFrom(), etc.?

Tags: c#, java, class

I am translating from Java to C# and have code similar to:

```java
Class<?> refClass = refChildNode.getClass();
Class<?> testClass = testChildNode.getClass();
if (!refClass.equals(testClass)) {
   // Do something
}
```

and elsewhere use `Class.isAssignableFrom(Class c)`... and similar methods

Is there a table of direct equivalents for class comparsion and properties and code-arounds where this isn't possible?

(The `<?>` is simply to stop warnings from the IDE about generics. A better solution would be appreciated)

Comment: `Class` => `Type`. camelCase => PascalCase ;)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
Type refClass = refChildNode.GetType();
Type testClass = testChildNode.GetType();
if (!refClass.Equals(testClass)) 
{
    ....
}
```

Have a look on System.Type class. It have [methods you need](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type_members.aspx).

Comment: you may want to mention the Type.IsAssignableFrom method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, to get the class (or in .NET speak, **Type**) you can use the following method:

```
Type t = refChildNode.GetType();
```

Now you have the Type, you can check equality or inheritance.  Here is some sample code:

```
public class A {}

public class B : A {}

public static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine(typeof(A) == typeof(B));                 // false
    Console.WriteLine(typeof(A).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(B)));  // true
    Console.WriteLine(typeof(B).IsSubclassOf(typeof(A)));      // true
}
```

This uses the System.Reflection functionality.  The full list of available methods is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type_methods.aspx).

Comment: Lol, sorry DerMike I didn't realise how patronizing this sounded!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at reflection (http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms173183(VS.80).aspx).

For example, your code would be:

```
Type refClass = refChildNode.GetType();
Type testClass = testChildNode.GetType();
if (refClass != testClass) 
{
    ....
}
```